# What is the proper technique for torching a creme brulee?

Tags: dessert, creme-brulee, blowtorch

Should you ever have your torch face downwards? When I do that I get huge flames. I try to torch it from the sides, but the sugar caramelizes very unevenly.

Comment: If you get huge flames when torching downwards, sounds like you're using a liquid gas camping cooker or similar. I don't think these are intended for torching; they're not safe to use in any way but standing firmly on a hard surface.

Comment: @leftaroundabout how do you tell liquid gas from gas-gas?

Comment: A liquid gas burner has a tank filled with, well, _liquid_ (usually butane, which despite being gaseous at atmospheric conditions stays easily liquid under some extra pressure). Yet normally, you only burn it as a gas as it boils off on top, and that gas can be well controlled for a hot, concentrated flame. But inverting such a burner will cause the gas to pour out in its liquid state, and as such it's much more messy. OTOH, a proper torch uses either gas which can never be liquid at room temperature, or makes sure that the liquid is vapourised before it leaves the pressure valve.

Answer (score 4):

There are good videos on the internet showing how to properly caramelize the sugar; are you doing things differently ?

Most of them just have the torch a couple of inches facing down over the sugar and in a slow side movement, caramelize the sugar.

The torch flame needs to be "blue" so that it is at its hottest.

Answer (score 0):

From the side but keep moving the torch constantly so as not to remain pointed at the same spot.